# Spring Binding / Velocity to a backing List

Tags: spring, data-binding, velocity

I'm attempting to bind a checkbox to a list of items on my POJO.

```
class SimplePOJO {
   private List <Key> selectedEntities = new ArrayList<Key>();
   public void setSelectedEntities(List <Key> a) { this.selectedEntities = a; }
   public List <Key> getSelectedEntities() { return this.selectedEntities; }
}
```

Velocity markup:

```
#springBind("command")
#springFormCheckBox("command.selectedEntities", "")
```

This doesn't work at all, just outputs the code verbatim.

Attempting to use standard items:

```
<input type="checkbox"
   #if ($command.selectedEntities.contains($item)) checked="checked" #end
   value="$item.key" />
```

Whenever I check any of the boxes and submit the form, my backing bean list remains empty.  How can I accomplish setting values into the list?

Note: I've also attempted the following in the POJO:

```
private List <Key> selectedEntities = new AutoPopulatingList <Key>(Key.class);
```

Environment: Spring 3.0.5, Velocity Engine 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding code I needed is:

```
#springFormCheckbox("command.selectedEntities[$velocityCount]", "id=entity$velocityCount value=$item.key #if($command.selectedEntities.contains($item.key)) checked=checked #end ")
```

I'm leaning towards having a typo in the live version instead of this simplified example.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need this:

```
#springFormCheckboxes("command.selectedEntities" $labels " " "")
```

Where `$labels` is a map from `Key` to labels of their checkboxes., the third parameter is a separator between checkboxes, the fourth one - arbitrary attributes.

**See also:**

- [16.4.5.3 Form input generation macros](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#views-form-macros)

Comment: I may not have explained this properly, but I have a list of objects I'm displaying to the user.  I have a checkbox (for each row) that I'd like to display to the user -- I need to know which of the rows they checked so that when they submit the form I can take the proper action.  The problem is I can't get them into a list of items.